# Update Leaflet marker className

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a `L.layerGroup()` called `var stopsLayer`. I want to iterate through it when certain parameters have been set by the user and "turn on" only those that match the user's input.

Turning on a marker implies it exhibiting one style versus the default. The method I have for accomplishing this is below.

```
stopsLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
  if (parameter === userInput) {
    layer.options.icon.options.className = 'icon-on';
  } else {
    layer.options.icon.options.className = 'icon-off';
  }
});
```

This "works" insofar as that, if I `console.log()` each of the markers and view the set `className` for that marker's `icon` property, it has been updated. Unfortunately, this change is not reflected in the map itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer. I had been using `setLayer` which was incorrect. There is an available method called `setIcon` which isn't as well documented.

I found a JSFiddle that demonstrates its use here: http://jsfiddle.net/JYF9u/8/

It's also listed as a method under markers in the documentation: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-seticon